# Vuetify not loading buttons and tables correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I originally had Vuetify working perfectly in my app but somewhere along the way the styles of components broke and I'm not sure how to fix it.

For example, here is my Vuetify table:

Reality:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

As far as I can tell everything is setup correctly, I will say, I started using SCSS inside the modules but I don't think that is the problem.

The functionality of `Vuetify` is working like sorting and things like that but just the styles are broken it appears.

Comment: you may need to include SCSS loader in webpack.

Comment: Is your vuetify page wrapped within v-app tag? If not this can sometimes cause vuetify components not to work properly. Especially after the vuetify 2.0 update.